# How to add animation to your mean stack application

Tags: javascript, css, animation, mean

I am designing a website using the MEAN stack, although there are numerous tutorials guiding how to go about the development of a web application using the MEAN stack, am not sure what is the best way to add animation to your application. Specifically, should all the animation just sit in the CSS and the html templates reference those classes. What about adding advanced animation features using the HTML5 canvas, what part of the project does it sit in. What is the most generic and cleanest way to add animation to your MEAN application, is ng-Animate in Angular the way to go about it ?

EDIT: What I specifically am looking to implement is an image of a box gift wrapped in a present with a ribbon hanging on the left side of it. Now I want a little boy/girl to drag the ribbon from left to right and unwrap the present. What is the best way to do this , that fits well with the MEAN stack?

Comment: This question is too broad, and too much a matter of opinion for Stack Overflow. Regarding whether "all" animation should be in the CSS, some things can't be animated with only CSS so the answer is no.

Comment: why don't you share your opinion, it might help me tailor my thought process

Comment: I'm trying to decide between Aos and Wow and the only real difference I can tell at this moment is that I have to pay for an Aos license

Answer (score 2):

This is a very broad question. It depends entirely on what kind of animations you hope to achieve.

Nonetheless, here are a few of my favourite libraries based on experience:

***AOS (Animate on Scroll)*** -

It is a pure CSS3 driven animation library that animates HTML elements in lots of useful ways.

**Demo**: http://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

**Code**: https://github.com/michalsnik/aos

**Implementation**:
You can use a package manager (npm or bower) to install for use in your project. Or download the source code directly.

***Spark Scroll*** -

A Javascript library that also handles scroll-based animations, as well as animations based on view-port visibility. Very powerful, and can be used to do things such as: draw borders on HTML elements when scrolled into view, trigger styling changes based on viewport visibility (ie. opacity), and many other things. Also, very customizable.

**Demo:** http://gilbox.github.io/spark-scroll/demo/

**Code:** https://github.com/gilbox/spark-scroll

**Implementation:**

Unfortunately, there is no native Javascript implementation for this library. Using Spark Scroll requires utilizing either ReactJS (Facebook) or Angular (Google).

Last but not least,

***WOW.js*** -

Another Javascript library that handles a lot of different animations.

**Demo:** http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/

**Code:** https://github.com/matthieua/WOW

**Implementation:** http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/docs.html

Honestly, I suggest you edit your post and identify what exactly you're trying to accomplish. I will update this answer after you conduct some research with the resources I've provided and determine what animations you wish to implement.

Comment: thankyou @jshbtchr for your answer, this definitely helped me get some insight into the available technologies. I have updated my question to highlight what implementation I am looking for.